# Linear equation solver Arduino,printing wrong answers

Tags: c, matrix, arduino, calculator, linear-algebra

Please help me any help will be appreciated.
I wrote a code in C to solve equations, but I don't know why some equations that I input into this calculator, give me wrong values, the algorithm is correct because I execute it in C and give me the correct answers but when I use it on the arduino sometimes it doesn't give me the correct answer, well here's the full code

and any help will be appreciated.

```
.
.
.
.

.
.
.
long jordan(){/*this do the gauss elimination for solve the equation*/
long FilaMax=0,k=0;
long double maxEl=0,tmp=0,fracc=0;
   lcd.clear();
for (colum=0; colum<cant-1; colum++) {
    /* search the maximun colum*/
    maxEl = abs(a[colum][colum]);
    FilaMax = colum;
    for (k=colum+1; k<cant; k++) {
        if (abs(a[k][colum]) > maxEl) {
            maxEl = abs(a[k][colum]);
            FilaMax = k;
        }
    }
    /* change the maximunby the actual row*/
    for (k=colum; k<cant+1;k++) {
        tmp = a[FilaMax][k];
        a[FilaMax][k] = a[colum][k];
        a[colum][k] = tmp;
    }
    /*lower cero's triangular matrix it's done here*/
    for (k=colum+1;k<cant; k++) {
        fracc = -a[k][colum]/a[colum][colum];
        for (fila=colum; fila<cant+1; fila++) {
            if (colum==fila) {
                a[k][fila] = 0;
            }else{
                a[k][fila] += fracc * a[colum][fila];
            }
        }
             } 
}
    char sr=' ';
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
if(a[cant-1][cant-1]==0){
    lcd.print("No solucion"); /* if there is no solution print this*/ 
    do{
    sr=keypad.waitForKey();
    }while(sr!='\n');
}else{                       /*is there values to print*/
for (colum=cant-1; colum>=0; colum--) {
    res[colum] = a[colum][cant]/a[colum][colum];
    for (k=colum-1;k>=0;k--) {
        a[k][cant] -= a[k][colum]*res[colum];
    }
}
colum=0;
    do{     
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("R");
            lcd.setCursor(1,0);
            lcd.print(colum+1);
            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(res[colum],DEC);
            sr=keypad.waitForKey();
            if(sr=='#') colum++;
            if (colum==cant) colum=0;
            if(sr=='\n') break;
    }while(1);
   }
   colum=0;
   fila=0;
   cant=0;
   sr=' ';
  return 0;
 }
```

Try the code with this:

```
 input:
    # size
    4
    elements:
    1 -2 1 1 2
    3 0 2 -2 -8
    0 4 -1 -1 1
    5 0 3 -1 -3 
 output:
 some numbers

 it should print without solution.
```

I first run the code in c on the pc, and the algorithm work perfect but when I copy to the arduino it doesn't work as expected the most of the time give the right answer to the linear system but somtimes fail

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us an example of incorrect output, along with what the correct output should be?

Comment: input:
    # size:
    4,   
    elements:
    {1 -2 1 1 2},
    {3 0 2 -2 -8},
    {0 4 -1 -1 1},
    {5 0 3 -1 -3} 
 output: R1 -3.333,   R2 3.2,  R3 6.33,  R4  5.33   but this is a wrong answer becuase this system doesn't have solution

Comment: Please can you help I'm been stuck with this code 2 days :c

Comment: Why don't you also post the entirety of your code. Even if the parts you removed aren't important to your problem, I can't effectively run (and replicate) your errors without the full code.

Comment: the full code is in the link, is a notepage, here´s the link, you can modify the code if you want, https://shrib.com/7uymq2yi in the page

Comment: Do you want the code here in the page?

Comment: Might be easier for other readers. Also, it won't be easily accidentally editable.

Comment: I agree.  Please use proper indentation too.  Also, translating important comments from Spanish to english would probably be good.

Comment: Please note that code with good comments and proper indentation will always get more help than code with bad comments and poor indentation :)

Comment: I've made all the changes thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a floating point error, the final value you are getting is very close to zero. [Demo](http://ideone.com/lWRRaU).

Add a small epsilon value to your final test to allow for floating point inaccuracies:

```
if(fabs(a[cant-1][cant-1]) < 0.000001){
    lcd.print("No solucion"); /* if there is no solution print this*/
```

Comment: Thanks so much now it's woking as expected :D thaaaanks

Answer (score 1):

Without much review - going out on a limb as I've had this error too.

Use floating point function rather than `int`

```
// maxEl = abs(a[colum][colum]);
maxEl = fabs(a[colum][colum]);
// other places too
```

Other issues may exist.

Comment: I'm doing the changes to run on the arduino, now the complete code is there, thanks so much

Comment: I made the changes but I getting the results yet :/

Comment: @user2461687 Did you change `abs()` --> `fabs()` in 3 places?

Comment: `String num=""; ,,, num=(String)numero; lgtd = num.length();` hints that code is standard not C - maybe C++ or an arduino extension.  If so, that `abs()` may be a false lead.  good luck.

Comment: I use for measure the lenght of the string for place the dot

Comment: @user2461687 If "can't use it " means `fabs()` then you can use it, but `abs()` may be overloaded and `abs(double)` does the same thing as `fabs(double)`.  I am not familiar enough with arduino to know.  Did not see that tag until late.

Comment: at the end of the entrada(); function I joint together numero1 and numero2 and I get a float. I don't see why does it affects

Comment: I refer to 'can´t use it' to the String num="" ,,,,, num=(String)numero; lgtd = num.length(); not to the fabs